# Is there a way to display SharePoint Online/Microsoft 365 iframe embeds in incognito/private browser windows?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, onedrive-for-business, embedded

I'm trying to understand Microsoft 365/Sharepoint Online embeds and get them to work in incognito/private browser windows.

Take the following simple HTML document:

```
<html>
  <body>
      <iframe
        title="integration"
        src="https://uniofnottm-my.sharepoint.com/:p:/g/personal/david_simpson_nottingham_ac_uk/EWhNtI2e3FlCm-SyUVlih70B8BdhDaa2hYsGnbdHVLv7IQ?e=E7fO5o&amp;action=embedview&amp;wdbipreview=true"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
      ></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

In a normal browser window, it displays just fine.

But in incognito/private browser windows, the "SharePoint Online / Sign In" screen is displayed:

[image]

If the [URL of the embed](https://uniofnottm-my.sharepoint.com/:p:/g/personal/david_simpson_nottingham_ac_uk/EWhNtI2e3FlCm-SyUVlih70B8BdhDaa2hYsGnbdHVLv7IQ?e=E7fO5o&action=embedview&wdbipreview=true) is taken and displayed in a new incognito/private browser window, it works fine:

[image]

**So, what's happening?**

✅ Paste the embed URL into any browser window and it just works.

❌ Use the embed URL in an iframe in an incognito window and...

1. the [embed URL](https://uniofnottm-my.sharepoint.com/:p:/g/personal/david_simpson_nottingham_ac_uk/EWhNtI2e3FlCm-SyUVlih70B8BdhDaa2hYsGnbdHVLv7IQ?e=E7fO5o&action=embedview&wdbipreview=true) does a 302 redirect,
2. another 302 redirect
3. checks to see if the current user is logged into SharePoint Online/Microsoft 365.
4. displays the "SharePoint Online / Sign In" screen

[image]

Worse still, having clicked on the "Sign In" button, the login modal fails to work when called from this screen within the iframe.

**Is there any way to prevent this from happening just because the embed is in an iframe?**

**Can you provide a working iframe that will display in an incognito browser window, without the login prompt?**

Comment: Can you please confirm the permissions behind the link? Is it set to "Anyone with link"? "..."` > "Copy Link" > "Link Settings" > "Anyone with link"

Comment: Yes, anyone with the link. Click on the “embed URL” link above and you’ll see it works w/o login.

Comment: Not sure what "embed URL" you are referring to. Is this something you see when you click the three dots beside the file name in SharePoint? When I copied your iframe code above, it works for me in an Incognito window without signing in: https://prnt.sc/kA_zOkikl2KY Codepen (open this in an Incognito window): https://codepen.io/gcwebdev/full/rNdxjOO

Comment: Interesting. Your codepen doesn't work for me in incognito/private windows in multiple browsers. The embed URL is built as described in "Get the URL to the public workbook" here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/embed-your-excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-sharepoint-or-onedrive-for-business-7af74ce6-e8a0-48ac-ba3b-a1dd627b7773

Comment: Strange! Can you try the Codepen on a different device?